# Bootstrap multiselect control - how to tell what's selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Using [this as an example](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/), I was able to get the drop down list working. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to determine what checkboxes are checked from the C# backend. I tried replacing the `<option>` tags with `<asp:CheckBox...` but the check boxes appear to the right of the drop down button, outside of the drop down all together. I also tried the code below:

```
    <select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="cheese" id="chkCheese" runat="server">Cheese</option>
        <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
        ...
    </select>
```

I can now access `chkCheese` from the CS file with the code above, but there are no properties for `.Checked` or `.Selected`. Any idea why?

Comment: What javascript have you added with the code?

Comment: Are you using Web Forms?

Comment: @SimpleSandman: I haven't added any javascript

Comment: @That-_-Guy__: Yes, this is a Web Forms project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `<option value="cheese" id="chkCheese" runat="server">` is going to resolve as an `HtmlGenericControl` so you're limited as to what you're going to get via standard properties.

One option is to embrace WebForms:

```
<asp:ListBox SelectionMode="Multiple" runat="server" CssClass="multiselect"  ID="Multi" multiple="multiple" >
   <asp:ListItem Value="cheese" >Cheese</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="tomato" >Tomato</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem Value="potato" >Potato</asp:ListItem>
</asp:ListBox>
```

And wire it up with a little jquery:

```
<script>
  $(function() {
    $('.multiselect').multiselect();
  });
</script>
```

On then on the server side you can look at the selected items

```
   if (this.Multi.Items.FindByValue("cheese").Selected)
   {
       //Add cheese to pizza?
   }
```

And of course, it's worth noting that just because you're using WebForms you can still use plain ol' HTML

```
    <select class="multiselect" multiple="multiple" name="select2">
        <option value="cheese" >Cheese</option>
        <option value="tomatoes">Tomatoes</option>
    </select>
```

Where on the server side you can look at  `Request.Form["select2"]` where multiple values will show up in a comma delimited string `"cheese,tomatoes"`

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much Joe - you just saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: I was going crazy, looking for the solution, your answer helped me